# vim: skip a block of code

Tags: vim

In emacs, I often need to work with terrifyingly large data files, where there are chunks of lines separated by empty lines. I can use `C-up` and `C-down` to move between these empty lines, namely the beginnings and ends of the code blocks.

Is there a similar functionality in vim which I can jump to the next/previous empty lines?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `:help paragraph`:

> A paragraph begins after each empty line,

You can use the paragraph jumps `}` and `{`, also with a prepended `[count]`.

Answer (score 8):

Use `}` to go down and `{` to go up. These motions are used to jump between "paragraphs".

See `:h motion.txt` for a good dose of mind blowage.

Note that you can also use the `p` (for "paragraph") text-object to quickly select/delete/change/indent/yank a "paragraph":

```
vip
dap
…
```

and use a "paragraph" as a range for Ex commands:

```
:'{,'}s/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 3):

...also see `[[` `]]` `[]` `][` to move between methods/functions in C/Python/more

...and `[m` `[M` `]M` `]m`  for Java  files